# Method calling in inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Let us suppose I have a parent class and a child class and I overloaded the one of the parent class method.

I am  assigning the child class object to a PARENT CLASS reference variable. I know that, while I try to call the parent class method it will call child class method.

But what is the reason behind that? what is program control flow? And what is going on inside the heap?

Comment: [Here's a blog from Eric Lippert about it.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/17/implementing-the-virtual-method-pattern-in-c-part-one.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The "magic" here is a lookup table.

When you declared the method as virtual, the method will be added to a table that is linked to the type, and all calls to the method will look up the address of the method to call in the table.

As such, instead of compiling in a call to a specific method at a specific address, the call will be compiled as a lookup and then a call to the value that was retrieved from the table.

For instance, let's say the base type has this table:

```
[1000]
```

For the first type, the method in question is at address 1000.

For the second type, this table looks like this:

```
[2000]
```

The same (overridden) method is now at address 2000.

If the method wasn't virtual, a call to it, like this call:

```
baseObject.Method1();
```

would be compiled to something like this:

```
call method at address 1000
```

But now instead it will look something like this:

```
get address to type virtual method table (vtable)
get adress from index 0 in the table
call the method at that address
```

Comment: can you please explain in detailed

Answer (score 1):

There are two key factors that make [dynamic dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) possible:

1. Every object of a particular type has a pointer to a [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) which contains (pointers to) virtual method implementations that are valid for *that* type.
2. Inheritance doesn't change the order of methods in the table (it can just append more methods at the end), so a method keeps the same index as you override it in child classes (and make more tables).

At run-time, compiler knows the index of the method you are calling, and implements the call as a lookup within the table using that index.

- Because of the (1) above, whichever type the object happens to have at run-time (as opposed to the type declared at compile-time), the lookup table containing correct method implementations will be used.
- And because of the (2) above, the index used by the compiler will "find" the correct method, even though the run-time type (and therefore lookup table) is unknown at compile-time.

In fact, the mechanism works for types that don't even exist yet! The method call can be written and compiled long before somebody makes the child type and method implementations specific to it.

*Disclaimer: The actual details of C# implementation are more complex than described above (e.g. interfaces require double-lookup, there is reflection etc.), but the basic idea stays the same.*